# Failing to insert data into database using prepared statement in PHP, no error reported

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a registration form that stores the users entered data into an MySQL database.
I was able to get it to work by manually setting the values, but learned that it was best to use prepared statements. This is what my PHP code looks like:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "accounts";

//Creating a new connection to the database
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Checking the connection
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}

//SQL string used to insert the data into the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "Failed";
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $_POST["name"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["passowrd"]);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
?>
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="formContent">
        <h3>Complete the following form to register an account:</h3>

        <form class="register" action="registration.php" method="post">

            Email: <input type="email" name="email" required> <br></br>
            Name: <input type="name" name="name" required> <br></br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" required> <br></br>
            Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirmed_password" required> <br></br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The listed code returns no error but the database is not updated. I have been busting my head for some time now, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be creating salts and hashing the passwords. Storing the submitted passwords in the database is not the correct way to do this.

Comment: @DevinCeartas I'm quite new to PHP and have come across that point, but I'm currently struggling with this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a typo for `password` (you have `$_POST['passowrd']`) and second, this is based on the example from the documentation:

```
# Prepare (use the OOP version of this library)
$query  =   $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
# Bind parameters and spell "password" correctly
$query->bind_param('sss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
# Execute
$query->execute();
# See if the row was created and echo success
echo ($query->affected_rows > 0)? 'Success!' : 'Failed';
```

You should be using `password_hash()` (storing) and `password_verify()` (validating) or a bcrypt equivalent library (if your version of php doesn't have those native functions). When using these functions, make sure your `password` column has like 255 character length so not as to cut off the password hash.

Comment: Now I just feel stupid :D.
Thanks a lot for the help and the example. I quite new to PHP and security seems to be the primary concern when doing most things, I will alter my approach to learning it. Thanks again.